# MySQL idempotent version of add column failing

Tags: mysql

MySQL here. Trying to add a column to a table in idempotent fashion. In reality it will be a SQL script that gets ran as part of an application data migration, so it will be ran over and over and I want to make sure that we only run it if the column does not already exist.

My best attempt so far:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE 
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myapp' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'fizzbuzz')
BEGIN 
  alter table myapp.mytable
    add column fizzbuzz tinyint(1) not null default false;
END
```

yields a vague syntax error:

```
"IF" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ALTER, ANALYZE, BEGIN, BINLOG, CACHE, ...
```

**Can anyone spot where my syntax is going awry?**

Comment: I believe the issue with the syntax error is that you cannot use if/else syntax outside of a procedure, like you can in MSSQL and probably others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
ALTER TABLE myapp.mytable
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT exists fizzbuzz TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE;
```

Comment: I don't believe the my MySQL version supports this: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT exists fizzbuzz TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE' at line 1`.

Comment: which version you ate using ?

Comment: sorry, it was only for MariaDB . see this there is a sample for MySQL. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/169458/mysql-how-to-create-column-if-not-exists